# Yii url rules overwriting eachother

Tags: php, yii

I'm having this problem where URL rules are overwriting each other.
The URL convention I need in my project is as follows:

```
test.com/Products/Decorations/                           //for Catalog listings in that Category
test.com/Products/Decorations/Winter-Decorations/8       //for Product listings in that Catalog
test.com/Products/Decorations/8/christmas-tree-bell.html //for viewing exact products
```

I'm not a Yii URL management expert and I know there's a million better ways to do this but my re-writing rules are as follows:

```
'/<rootCategory>/<categoryName>/<id>' => 'catalogs/index',
'/<rootCategory>/<categoryName>/<catalogTitle>/<id>' => 'products/index',
'/<rootCategory>/<categoryName>/<id>/<url_slug>' => 'products/view',
```

Now what's happening is, the rule for viewing the products isn't working when the rules are in this order. I get an error:

> 500 Trying to get property of non-object.

But when i move the last rule one up, like so:

```
'/<rootCategory>/<categoryName>/<id>' => 'catalogs/index',
'/<rootCategory>/<categoryName>/<id>/<url_slug>' => 'products/view',
'/<rootCategory>/<categoryName>/<catalogTitle>/<id>' => 'products/index',
```

The rule for listing all the products in a catalog doesn't work throwing the same error message, but the rule for viewing the product works.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second and third routing rules are duplicative; Yii will always match the former rule, thereby ignoring the other. The resulting errors you encounter are because parameters don't match the action.

Use more specific pattern matching in your rules, for example:

```
'/<rootCategory>/<categoryName>/<id:\d+>/<url_slug>' => 'products/view',
'/<rootCategory>/<categoryName>/<catalogTitle>/<id:\d+>' => 'products/index',
```

The pattern `:\d+` matches a numeric value. Using the rules above, the path `/Products/Decorations/Winter-Decorations/8` will *not* match the first rule (because `Winter-Decorations` is not numeric) but will match the second rule. This is the behavior you're seeking.

See ["URL Rules" in Yii Framework 2.0 API Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules).

Comment: Thank you very much, adding the regexp to the id helped. I knew what was causing the error but didn't know why the rules were messing up. Never was too knowledgeable about regexp either.